# Error in ScaleData() and PrepDR5() in Seurat

Tags: r, scale, seurat, rna-seq

I'm currently trying the Seurat on a new dataset that I have. I got to the point of scailing the data and performing linear dimensinal reduction but I encounter the error said " Error in ScaleData() and PrepDR5()". What should I do in these steps?
I would be really aprricate if someone able to help me. Thanks

[image: This is my code]

Here is the link to the data I'm trying: https://github.com/FredHutch/seatrac-hackday-2023/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file   (I'm trying darrah week 25 filtered cells)

The link to Seurat tutorial: https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial

I expect to solve the problem. I have tried the code again but seems like it can't work